# Chemistry in Latex

Tags: chemistry

I use the texmaker editor to write latex. To write chemistry formulas, what extension do you recommend? I downloaded it from Miktex that have a lot.

Thanks

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to *typeset* chemical formulas, don't you? Then TeXmaker would not be related to your problem. Otherwise, if you talk about the *input* of chemical formulas you should add this piece of information.

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this thread, please go back to your previous questions and accept the answers that helped you.

Comment: There are several packages available: `chemfig`, `mhchem`, `chemformula` to name a few. Try Google "latex chemistry".

Comment: @TeXnician Chemical reactions and organic formulas, mainly for examinations. I have seen that there are many extensions and I do not know which one to download for texmaker.

Comment: I've already searched. If what I was asking for was the advice of someone you are using, that is fine. To avoid walking trying ...

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to be more clear. If I understand you correctly, you might change the title to "Packages for Typesetting Chemical Formulas" and then ask for recommendations of packages (not extensions) to typeset chemical formulas. Show that you have done some research by finding some examples (Google). TeXmaker and Miktex are irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit example with `mhchem`- Here there is a documentation [mhchem](https://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem).

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\ce{H2SO4}, \quad 

\ce{^{115}_{70}Be}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beryllium-115 with atomic number 70? What the heck is this:)

Comment: :-) it is an example.

Comment: It hurts my chemist's eyes so much:D